# Using MVC View LabelFor/TextFor with expression with unknown return type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-expressions

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I have a web app where the user has an administrative portal which can be used to edit certain settings. There are lots of editable settings, so I'd like to create a single set of inheritable MVC objects such that I can just specify a settings object (which is just a row in a table) and it will display the settings, offer search functionality, the ability to add/remove entries, etc.

**What I have so far**

An inheritable controller object has been created. It works by taking the object type (like a `User` object) and creating an array of `AdminField` objects. Each represents a row in the database. The derived controller class also passes metadata for each field as flags, so the derived controller code would look like this:

```
public class UserController : AdminBaseController<UserViewModel, User>
{
    public UserController(Context context) : 
        base(context, new AdminField<User>[] {
            new AdminField<User>(u => u.UserId, AdminFieldFlags.Hidden | AdminFieldFlags.IsID),
            new AdminField<User>(u => u.UserName, AdminFieldFlags.Searchable | AdminFieldFlags.Sortable | AdminFieldFlags.Editable | AdminFieldFlags.EditLink, "User Name"),
            new AdminField<User>(u => u.Password, AdminFieldFlags.Editable),
            new AdminField<User>(u => u.AccessLevel, AdminFieldFlags.Editable)
        }, "User")
    {
    }
}
```

The first parameter is a lambda that shows how to get the referenced field from the object.

Here's the method signature for the `AdminField` constructor:

```
public AdminField(Expression<Func<TMaintainedType, object>> field, AdminFieldFlags flags, string displayName = null)
```

The field data is also accessible to the ViewModel, so in the View we have code like this:

```
@foreach (var f in Model.Fields.Where(f => !f.Hidden))
{
    //Gets original expression for this field
    var expression = Model.ExpressionFromField<UserViewModel>(f);
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(expression, new { @class = "control-label col-3" })
        @Html.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
}
```

Viola! The field label and edit box are displayed!

**The Problem**

The method signature for `AdminField` takes a `Expression<Func<TMaintainedType, object>>` object. This works great for `string`s, but (based on my limited understanding) forces a boxing/unboxing for `int` fields, and thus the stored expression changes from (for example) `u => u.UserId` to `u => Convert(u.UserId)`. Since I am saving an array of fields, the return type needs to be `object` (since it can differ), so I can't remove the `Convert`.

As a result, when the field grabs the expression and the field is `int32`, I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` error on my LabelFor line: `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`

**The Question**

How can I convert `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to `Expression<Func<T, int>>` dynamically?

I'm currently getting around the issue by creating a special method just for integers that removes the conversion, but that means that

1. I need to check for an integer every time (which makes for a LOT
   of If statements in the Views), and
2. If I need any other value type, I'll need to create yet another special method and use switch/if statements in the views to select the right method.

Help! Let me know if you need any more information; it's always hard to know what to include.

Comment: out of interest, why didn't you use a type parameter instead of object? e.g. `Expression<Func<TMaintained, TReturn>>`

Comment: The return type is associated with `AdminField<T>`. Using a return type parameter would require changing that to `AdminField<T, TReturn>`. I need to have arrays of `AdminField` objects with different return types, so that doesn't work. The only alternatives I could think of (i.e. covariance) would only work with reference types, and most of my types are value types.

Comment: I've been racking my brain to work it out, but no dice yet; interesting challenge ;)

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama, I appreciate it. :) My "plan B" solution below improved a bit by using the non-expression `HtmlHelper` methods (i.e. `Html.Editor` instead of `Html.EditorFor`, which basically just gives me free MVC validation. It doesn't solve the root problem, but the workaround is gradually getting less painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to dynamically make this conversion, but solved my problem using the approach detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081579/reusable-mvc-code-handling-value-types-in-linq-expressions?noredirect=1#comment63602460_38081579).

I gave up on using the `HtmlHelper` objects and instead used the `name` properties of html elements to bind values to the data model. Because the `name` is a `string`, I could convert everything to a `string`, solving my data type issue. And MVC binding handles the conversion of edited values back to their original types. The combination gives me two-way support for all my needed data types (`string`s, value types, and `nullable` value types).