# Reusable MVC code: handling value types in linq expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-expressions

**Overview**

I am writing an MVC set that is intended to provide basic search/add/edit/delete functionality for an Entity Framework object. It also does some fancy things like supporting dropdowns filled from other tables using attributes.

The main object in play is an inheritable generic controller (`AdminController<T>` where `T` is the EF object) containing an array of `AdminField<T>`, each element of which represents a field/property in `T`. `AdminController<T>` can generate an `AdminViewModel<T>` object. Below is a Visio chart of the relationships between those objects.

[image]

**The Problem**

My problem is in the Views. To display values, I'm using the `Html.EditorFor`/`HiddenFor`/`TextboxFor` helpers. A hyper-simplified view simply loops through the field and displays their values, allowing edits if they're editable fields. This looks like:

```
@model AdminViewModel<ExampleEFObject>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var f in Model.Fields)
    {
        var expression = Model.ExpressionFromField(f);

        <label class="control-label col-md-3">@f.DisplayName</label>

        @if (!f.Editable)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

Well, that's what I **want** it to look like. It works just fine with fields/properties that are reference types. With value types, however, I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` error on the `EditorFor` line: "*Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.*"

This is because the `ExpressionFromField` method, which returns an expression accessing an instance of `T` within the ViewModel, has a return type of `Expression<Func<AdminViewModel<T>, object>>`. Because it returns an object type, boxing is forced when generating the expression so that instead of (for example) `t => t.Count`, my method is actually returning `t => Convert(t.Count)`.

**Current Workaround**

My current workaround is to have a second method defined as `Expression<Func<AdminViewModel<T>, int>> IntExpressionFromField(AdminField<T> field)`. Because it returns an `int`, it doesn't force boxing in the expression. However, it makes my views extremely ugly:

```
@model AdminViewModel<ExampleEFObject>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var f in Model.Fields)
    {
        var expression = Model.ExpressionFromField(f);
        var intExpression = Model.IntExpressionFromField(f);

        <label class="control-label col-md-3">@f.DisplayName</label>

        @if (!f.Editable)
        {
            if (intExpression == null)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(intExpression, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if (intExpression == null)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(intExpression, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            }
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

Worse, this only supports 1 value type (`int`). I'd also like to support decimal, long, and whatever else--preferably without having to create custom methods for each as well as all the logic to safeguard against other types.

**Help!**

I'd love to find an elegant, easy way to resolve this issue. If none exists, I think my next step would be to stop using the `Html` helper methods; however, this would require breaking consistency with the rest of the application and I don't even know that it would solve the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's overall a bad practice to pass your EF object to View. You would probably have to create some abstract FormViewModel that contain implementations of some abstract FieldViewModels(with editor templates, like DatePickerViewModel, TextBoxViewModel and so on), and in your controller you have to transform that viewmodel to update operations for your Entity Framework entity, or into DTO if you have a service layer.

Comment: It might overall be not worth it, as it does not allow you to do complex layouts or fancy user interaction, so switching to ViewModels and manual code to update entities is viable, if you have not that much entities

Comment: @raderick: Thanks for responding. I haven't passed my EF object to the view, only a generic ViewModel. However, if that is bad practice I'd love to understand why so I can choose a better approach in the future.

The reason I'm doing this is because there are dozens of object types which only require some basic maintenance functions. I want to avoid having dozens of identical MVC sets.

The approach you described seems incredibly heavy and limiting as you said, but I'll keep it in mind as a fallback option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to fix this issue using my existing approach, I tried the approach I mentioned at the end: abandoning `HtmlHelper` methods. This worked great and I wish I'd done it a long time ago.

MVC ViewModel binding is accomplished using the "name" property, so to manually bind to my model I needed to get the unqualified property name (i.e. for the field expressed as `cust => cust.Records.Address.State`, I needed the string `SelectedItem.Records.Address.State` (where `SelectedItem` is the ViewModel object that contains the displayed value). My `AdminField<T>` object already had a `MemberExpression` property, so I just used the `ToString()` method, removed the parameter, and prepended the ViewModel object name. Ugly, I know, but reliable and easy.

Before, I needed the expression to feed the `HtmlHelper` object, but now I just needed the value, so I replaced my `ExpressionFromField()` method with a simpler `GetValue()` method which returns the `string` value. It's important that it returns a `string`; this conversion allows me to read and write all value types (because the ViewModel binding handles the conversion of edited values back to the original property type).

My new views look like this:

```
@model AdminViewModel<ExampleEFObject>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var f in Model.Fields)
    {
        var propertyName = f.PropertyName(f); //unqualified, can contain multiple parts
        var value = Model.GetValue(f);        //uses the field expression to retrieve the value
                                              //of a "T SelectedItem" object in the ViewModel
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">@f.DisplayName</label>

        @if (!f.Editable)
        {
            <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" name="@propertyName" type="text" value="@value" />
        }
        else
        {
            <input class="form-control" name="@propertyName" type="text" value="@value" />
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

Much cleaner!

One thing I lose with this approach is validation. From here, I can add javascript validation or create templates to duplicate the data validation that `HtmlHelper` automatically adds.  Either way, no big deal.

Hope this helps someone.

Note: @[Ivan Stoeve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) recommended using `Html.Editor`/`Html.Textbox` etc., which accept a binding via the property name rather than an expression. This still leaves me without the strongly typed expressions in the view, but it gives me back validation so I think it will be worth adjusting it. It will also clear up some ugly string manipulation I had to do when adding dropdown options. :)

Comment: Can't you just use the `HtmlHelper` methods that accept `string` instead of `Expression` (the ones w/o `For` suffix, e.g. `TextBox` instead of `TextBoxFor` etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I might use that. Ultimately the learning for me was the binding model and pulling the property name to the view; the whole idea of using the `HtmlHelper` was to use the strongly typed expression while retaining a reusable layout.

Still, this will at least give me free validation. I'll take that.